# In Windows 10, is it possible to trigger a local login from a remote computer?

Tags: windows-10, auto-login

Is there a way, either through SSH or an RDP connection, to force a Windows 10 machine to log in to an account locally? As in, have the PC log itself in as if someone were sitting in front of it?

One way I can think of would be to create a PowerShell script that, when run, would prompt for the local account's username and password. It would then modify the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` registry key with those values, then perform a reboot. I would also need to create a startup script for that user that would remove this key when the user logs in so that autologin isn't enabled permanently. I haven't tried this yet, but I believe it should work.

But is there a built-in way or a more elegant way to achieve this? Also, are there problems or security risks with the method I proposed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works and is much simpler than what I proposed in my question:

- RDP into the machine
- Start a command prompt as administrator
- Run the following command: `tscon 1 /dest:console`

This disconnects the RDP session and logs the computer in locally.